# RecyclerView and CardView don't support compileSdkVersion

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, build.gradle, android-cardview

recently I implemented `RecyclerView` and `CardView` in gradle file but the version of both of them doesn't match the `compileSdkVersion` this is my build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mostafa.tostrategies"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'

}
```

Comment: What happens when you do make the versions match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace these

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

With

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

Comment: thanx, it worked.

Comment: most welcome! if worked then can you accept it as answer

Comment: done done done.

Answer (score 1):

As you can check in the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#28-0-0-alpha1):

> Note: 28.0.0-alpha1 is a pre-release version to support the Android P developer preview.

To fully test your app's compatibility with Android P and begin using new APIs you have to use:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-P'

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 'P'
    }
    ...
}
```

Also pay attention to use the **same version** of support libraries.

Instead if you want to use the version v26 just use:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

The major version of support libraries and `recyclerview` and `cardview` must be equal to `compileSdkVersion`

for example if you use `recyclerview-v7:xx.yy.zz` your `compileSdkVersion` must be xx

Comment: Error in appcompat implementation 
(com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0)